# Код Хэмминга. Проверочная и пораждающая матрица

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно сгенерировать ниже приведенные матрицы не разделяя их по частям?

"Порождающая матрица G может быть представлена двумя матрицами, единичной и
добавочной."

Добавочная матрица это транспонировнная часть проверочной матрицы(не единичной то есть).

[image: задание]

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;

    static void transp(byte[,] mas)
    {
        byte[,] temp = new byte[mas.GetLength(1), mas.GetLength(0)];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                temp[i, j] = mas[j, i];
            }
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(temp[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    Console.Write("Введите информационную комбинацию: ");
    string alpha = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Информ.комбинация = " + alpha);
    int k = alpha.Length;
    Console.WriteLine("Число информационных разрядов = {0}", k);
    double r = Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(k + 1 + Math.Log(k + 1, 2), 2));
    Console.WriteLine("Число корректирующих разрядов = {0}", r);
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(k + r);
    Console.WriteLine("Число разрядов закодированной кодовой комбинации = {0}", n);
    
    byte[,] A = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(r), k];
    //Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            //A[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 1);
            Console.Write("Введите число: " + "\t");
            A[i, j] = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Матрица A[r,k] = ");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {   
           Console.Write(A[i, j] + "\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Транспонированнаяа матрица A[r,k] = ");
    transp(A);
    byte[,] E = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(r), Convert.ToInt32(r)];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                E[i, j] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                E[i, j] = 0;
            }
    
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Матрица E[r,r] = ");
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(E[i, j].ToString() + "\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    byte[,] E1 = new byte[k, k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                E1[i, j] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                E1[i, j] = 0;
            }
    
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Матрица E[k,k] = ");
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(E1[i, j].ToString() + "\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Двухмерный массив заполнить?

Comment: У меня получается это по отдельности заполнить, но как в одной матрице это реализовать не понятно.

Comment: Вы можете заполнить массив по частям, 2 вложенных цикла, просто не от 0 до конца делайте, а от определенного индекса. Если нужно конкретное решение, показывайте код конкретного примера, минимальный **воспроизводимый** пример, что дано, что надо получить.

Comment: Обнаружил, что вы уже ранее задавали этот вопрос. Вместо того чтобы постить дубликаты, отредактируйте исходный вопрос.

Comment: В коде у меня реализовано по частям, но не вместе.